# Automate the creation of 19 data.frames on R

Tags: r

I need to create 19 data.frames from 19 different rasters, then combine them into one data frame.

I use this example code to do it for now, as you can see

```
raster1 <- ("~/Documents/QGIS/Raster/exemple_1.tif")
raster1_val <- getValues(raster1)
raster1_df <- data.frame(raster1_val)
raster1_df <- na.omit(raster1_df)

raster2 <- ("~/Documents/QGIS/Raster/exemple_2.tif")
raster2_val <- getValues(raster)
raster2_df <- data.frame(raster2_val)
raster2_df <- na.omit(raster2_df)
```

and this 19 times, then

```
raster_19<-cbind(raster1_df, raster2_df,...., raster19_df) 
raster_19["Source"]="Native_area"
```

So, I try to found a code to automate this rather than to have infinitely long codes.
Maybe someone have a idea. Thank you

Comment: Read about list.files and lapply. Keep your dataframes in a list. See relevant post for importing multiple files - https://stackoverflow.com/q/11433432/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for all files in one step. Like this:

```
library(terra)
ff <- paste0("~/Documents/QGIS/Raster/exemple_", 1:19, ".tif")
x <- rast(ff)
d <- as.data.frame(x, na.rm=TRUE)
```